# Authentication for web api using azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-api-apps

I need to implement authentication for azure web api using azure active directory.

client app(which consumes webapi) may or may not be in azure. how i need to authenticate user, where i should generate token if my app is not in azure(if it is IOS app). authentication should work in all cases even if client app is in azure or not.

Please let me now the best procedure to implement authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the client app in Azure AD as a native app in the case of a mobile app. Then you define the API there, and add your client permissions to access it. You can optionally customize the available permissions through the API app's manifest in Azure AD. Then when your mobile app opens, you would have to authenticate with Azure AD, and then request an access token for the API. That you can then use to authenticate requests.

I can't answer this question in too great detail because it is quite a large topic and how it is done also depends on your platform. There is a [sample app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios) that you can check which does exactly what you want. The whole list of examples for native apps can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-code-samples#native-application-to-web-api).

Comment: This is what I did but I am facing a small problem, my client is able to fetch the token but when I pass it to the API it returns unauthorized. I am not able to figure out what is amiss . My client is a simple desktop console app.

Comment: Probably means your API doesn't consider the token valid. Knowing nothing about your setup, I can only mention that you should check that the expected `audience` and `authority` are correct. Maybe post a question about this with some code from the API?

Comment: As per my understanding, audience for web API should be used as resource in the client,  and I am able to get the token for that resource.

Comment: You can inspect the token in e.g. https://jwt.io. Check the `aud` claim value matches the one you have configured in the API. And then really make a question about the problem :)

Comment: I am following the instruction here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet) and I am able to get it authenticated successfully when running the WEB API locally. But when I deploy the same thing to Azure (Free Account) I am getting Unauthorized from the WEB API. The only change on the client is the request URI and there is no change on the WEB API code.

Answer (score 0):

App Service to use different authentication providers [Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication),[Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication),[Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-google-authentication),[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication),[Twitter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-twitter-authentication).
We can set any type of Authentication/Authorization in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/).More info about how to use authentication for API Apps in Azure App Service, please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-dotnet-user-principal-auth).

> By default, App Service provides authentication but does not restrict authorized access to your site content and APIs. You must authorize users in your app code.

[image]